# POST nested json in postman formdata

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, nested, postman

actually, I wanted to send nested JSON with an image to creating user profile image in Django, and the main issues addressed to I cant fill the nested objects

this is my json that successfully post in raw mode :

```
 {
"id": 1,
"bio": "salam manam",
"user": {
    "username": "amirlesani",
    "first_name": "",
    "password":"somepasword"
    "last_name": "",
    "email": ""
},
"user_type": {
    "user_type": "br"
             }
 }
```

But when I want to fill up the form data same as that way its shown an error like this

user_type: this field is required!

user: this field is required!

serlializers:

```
 class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    user_type = UserTypeSerializer()
    images = ProfileImageSerializer(source='profileimage_set', many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'bio', 'user', 'images', 'user_type')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        usertype = validated_data.pop('user_type')
        type = UserTypeSerializer.create(UserTypeSerializer(), validated_data=usertype)

        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)

        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, bio=validated_data.pop('bio'), user_type=type)
        images_data = self.context.get('view').request.FILES

        for image_data in images_data.values():
            ProfileImage.objects.create(userprofile=userprofile, image=image_data, user_type=type)

        userprofile.save()
        return userprofile
```

Comment: share your `models.py` and `serializers.py`, `views.py`

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , u must distinct the imageUploader from the nested json , and connect ur images to ur data with a foreign key